# Express Validator: field mandatory if another field has a value, but rejected otherwise?

Tags: express-validator

I'm trying to write a validation chain with the following reqs:

- Field `type` is mandatory and one of a set of values
- Field `negativeName` is **mandatory** if `type === 'binary'` but otherwise **shouldn't be allowed**

The closest I've been able to get is:

```ts
checkExact([
  body('type').isIn(['binary', 'trend']).withMessage('Invalid type'),
  body('negativeName')
    .if((value, { req }) => req.body.type === 'binary'),
    .isString()
    .isLength({ min: 1, max: 250 })
    .withMessage('negativeName required for binary')
], { message: 'Invalid field' })
```

This gets me close but not all the way; if `trend` is set to `binary` the `negativeName` field becomes mandatory, but if `binary` is set to another value `negativeName` is still being allowed.

Some examples:

| JSON | Works? |
| --- | --- |
| `{ "type": "binary", "negativeName": "blah" }` | ✔ Happy path |
| `{ "type": "binary" }` | ✔ Properly rejected because no `negativeName` |
| `{ "type": "binary", "negativeName": "" }` | ✔ Properly rejected because `negativeName` is empty |
| `{ "type": "trend" }` | ✔ Happy path |
| `{ "type": "trend", "negativeName": "blah" }` | ❌ *Want* it to reject, but no error is thrown |
| `{ "type": "trend", "blurgh": "blech" }` | ✔ Properly rejected by `checkExact` because `blurgh` isn't in the validation chain |